# jQuery : how create input / remove (keyup event)

Tags: jquery

I need to create/remove an input during an event.

The problem is that I need to create the `input` tag only once.

If I use jQuery's `.off()`, the event happens once, so the remove doesn't work anymore.

```js
$('#first').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    console.log('add');
    $(this).after('<input id="two" type="text" name="lot">');
    //$(this).off();
  } else {
    console.log('delete');
    $('#two').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="first" type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my code : https://codepen.io/Jennifer_C/pen/Ermqqd

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In js(vanila) you pass {'once': true} as option. Don't know how it is in jQuery. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the element with the id `two` exists, if it does, then you know you don't need to add the element anymore, if it doesn't exist, you can add the element. Lastly, if there are no more characters (ie `$(this).val().length <= 0`) you can remove the input:

```js
$('#first').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length && !$("#two").length) {
    $(this).after('<input id="two" type="text" name="lot">');
  } else if (!$(this).val().length) {
    $('#two').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="first" type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

See working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOgrYQ)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a check whether the next element has `id="two"` to the `if`-condition:

```js
$('#first').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0 && !this.nextElementSibling.id === "two") {
    console.log('add');
    $(this).after('<input id="two" type="text" name="lot">');
  } else {
    console.log('delete');
    $('#two').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="first" type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```